# python selenium error logging in pop up window

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am clicking on a hyperlink, on clicking which opens up a pop up window. I want to enter user name and password and then hit log in button but I am getting an error of invisible element. My username and password fields are getting populated but on click of log in button it gives error

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome( )
driver.get('https://www.website/')

window_before=driver.window_handles[0]
print('window before', window_before)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("LoginModal").click()
window_after= driver.find_element_by_class_name("loginwindow_2")

print('window after', window_after)

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("Enter")

driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(" password here")
```

It is populating username and password properly but when I type this it gives me an error.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("bluebutton2")
```

Error

```
 File "C:/Users/myfile/mucode.py", line 21, in 
<module>

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 elements on page with class name `"bluebutton2"`. The first one is hidden, that's why you get `ElementNotVisibleException`. You just need to use more specific selector to match required element. Try below:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[valign="middle"]>button.bluebutton2').click()
```

*Update*

To handle input fields you can use below code to wait some time and avoid `ElementNotVisibleException`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys("Enter")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("password here")
```

Comment: Hi now it is giving error at the following line saying element is not found there>>>>>>>>>>> driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("Enter")

Comment: Can you please help me with the code from that line.?

Comment: Do you mean `NoSuchElementException`? On `driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("Enter")`?

Comment: Yes! selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` and `ElementNotVisibleException` actually not the same :) Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

try this, may not work and I'm assuming you are trying to click on the login button

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', driver.find_element_by_class_name('bluebutton2'))
```

Comment: Hi, That didn't work but now it is giving me same error of element not visible at this line only >>>>>>>>>>>>> driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("Enter")